# Unable to run command 'StripNIB <filename>.nib' - XCode

Tags: xcode, static, nib

I have a project in XCode with a static library. I am able to build it with XCode 4.5.1, but when I try to build it with XCode 5 I get this error for several xib files:

Unable to run command 'StripNIB filename.nib' - this target might include its own product.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I removed the xib from the static library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by removing the xib files from the static library.